# PHP - Replace subfolder in link (in order to change language)

Tags: php, redirect

This is my first post on this forum, so please forgive any of my unintentional errors.

So, let me try to explain what my problem is:

I have a two language website with a folder structure like this:

mywebsite/ru (russian)
and
mywebsite/en (english)

When I'm on the russian version of the website, the links to all categories look like this:

subdomain.domain.com/ru/clients/myclient, 
subdomain.domain.com/ru/services/myservice
etc

and when I'm on the english version of the website, the links look the same, the only difference being the /en/ subfolder instead of the /ru/ subfolder:

subdomain.domain.com/en/clients/myclient, 
subdomain.domain.com/en/services/myservice

What I'd like to do, is have two links in the website's header, one for english and one for russian, and these links should automatically switch the language to the english/russian version, of the current page.

So, if I'm on subdomain.domain.com/ru/services/myservice and click the english link, I want to be redirected to subdomain.domain.com/en/services/myservice
Or, if I'm on

So if i'm on subdomain.domain.com/ru/clients/myclient and click the english link, I want to be redirected to subdomain.domain.com/en/clients/myclient

So basically, I need a php script (or javascript, if it's easier) that will keep the existing link and changes the /ru/ part to /en/ and viceversa.

I tried searching the web for a solution but can't find one that actually works for me.
Thank you very much!

Comment: my eyes are bleeding when i see this :( please formate your question properly

Comment: Do you have only 2 languages en/ru ?

Comment: Why don't you come with some code ? Some work ? Something specific rather too broad question.

Comment: @Serhat Akay and NullPoiиteя ღ : Sorry for being so ignorant. I'll try to keep in mind your suggestions for the future. Thanks again to **TiMESPLiNTER** for his perfect solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using absolute links you could do something like

```
// REQUEST_URI contains your current URI like '/en/services/myservice'
// split this URI by '/'
$uriParts = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

// get all values after 'en'
$uriPartsWithoutLang = array_slice($uriParts, 2);

// prefix the new URI with 'ru' and 
// concatinate the remaining array values with '/' again
$newUri = '/ru/' . implode('/', $uriPartsWithoutLang);

// print out the link
echo '<a href="' , $newUri , '">Russia</a>';
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I wish I could up-vote your explanation, but I can't :(. Anyway, it works like a charm! Thanks a lot, again!

Comment: But you can mark it as correct solution to your problem can't you?

Comment: Oh God, I'm such a noob :)) Yeah, I certainly can.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Us str_replace function for this

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

```
 $url = "subdomain.domain.com/ru/clients/myclient";
 $newurl =  str_replace("ru","en",$url);
```